# Method doesn't bind to event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

Im trying to use MVC pattern in winforms but when I try invoke event it is always null. I pass GameView form to Game class to which I bind CityButtonPressed method to event but when I run it it seems like if nothing was bound.

```
class Game
{
    private readonly IGameView _gameView;

    public Game(IGameView view)
    {
        _gameView = view;
        _gameView.CityButtonPressed += CityButtonPressed;
    }

    public void CityButtonPressed(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
          //do something
    }
}

public interface IGameView
{
   event EventHandler CityButtonPressed;
}

public partial class GameView : Form,IGameView
{
    public event EventHandler CityButtonPressed;

    public GameView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected virtual void OnButtonPressed(EventArgs e)
    {
        CityButtonPressed?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnButtonPressed(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var gameView = new GameView();
        var game = new Game(gameView);
        Application.Run(new GameView());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse the `CityButtonPressed` event handler in `GameView`

Comment: This doesn't look very MVC to me. Your `Game` class looks like both a Model and a Controller combined. And, either way, it shouldn't know anything about button presses.

Comment: There is nothing about the code you've posted that shows it doesn't work. Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Maybe the `GameView` is recreated after the event is registered?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the constructor of `GameView` and check if it is called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cut down version of your code ***that shows it works***.

```
void Main()
{
    var view = new GameView();
    var game = new Game(view);
    view.OnButtonPressed();
}

public interface IGameView
{
    event EventHandler CityButtonPressed;
}

class Game
{
    private readonly IGameView _gameView;


    public Game(IGameView view)
    {
        _gameView = view;
        _gameView.CityButtonPressed += CityButtonPressed;
    }

    public void CityButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pressed");
    }
}

public partial class GameView : IGameView
{
    public event EventHandler CityButtonPressed;

    public void OnButtonPressed()
    {
        if (CityButtonPressed == null) 
            Console.WriteLine("null");
        CityButtonPressed?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

When I run that I get `Pressed` on the console. All I did is refactor your code to get it down to the minimal amount required for it to run.

It would seem you're not wiring it up correctly or your not showing us the actual minimal amount of code required.

---

### UPDATE

You're creating two `GameView` instances. There's your problem.

```
    var gameView = new GameView();
    var game = new Game(gameView);
    Application.Run(new GameView());
```

Instead, try this:

```
    var gameView = new GameView();
    var game = new Game(gameView);
    Application.Run(gameView);
```

Comment: I found out that when i run the OnButtonPressed method in the main method as you did, it works fine but when it runs after the actual button was pressed it show null exception. I updated the main post, should be enough to reproduce now.

Comment: @AdamKotvas - Problem solved. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `Game` class is instantiated with the `GameView` instance before you invoke `CityButtonPressed`. For example:

```
private Game game;
    protected virtual void OnButtonPressed(EventArgs e)
    {
      game=  new Game(this);
        if (CityButtonPressed == null)   
            MessageBox.Show("null");  
        CityButtonPressed?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
```

It is not a good solution for you because you will need the `Game` instance somewhere but the `CityButtonPressed` should not be null anymore.